# Progress bar on correct answers

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar

I'm doing a little maths game in android studio, to go from level one the player needs to answer 10 questions in a row. I have the score counting and when the player gets a certain score they get to another level. I would like to add a progress bar that progresses with the correct answers. So say when the player needs to have 10 correct answers in a row but has 5, it will be filled 50% etc.
This is the code that counts the score:

```
  Button answerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerButton);
    answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                answerUser = Integer.parseInt(numberEdit.getText().toString());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                answerUser = 0;
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Error, masdaohfisahfi9aw",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(answer == answerUser)
            {
                TextView Scores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
                score ++;

                String String3 = String.valueOf(score);
                Scores.setText(String3);
                answerText.setText("Well done!");
                do {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    Random rand1 = new Random();
                    number = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                    numbers1 = rand1.nextInt(10) + 1;
                    TextView number1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number1);
                    TextView number2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number2);

                    String String1 = String.valueOf(number);
                    String String2 = String.valueOf(numbers1);
                    number1.setText(String1);
                    number2.setText(String2);
                    answer = number + numbers1;
                    answerUser = 0;
                    numberEdit.setText("");

                }

                while(answer==answerUser);
                if(score == 10)
                {
                    alert();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                answerText.setText("Wrong");
                TextView Scores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
                score = 0;
                String String3 = String.valueOf(score);
                Scores.setText(String3);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? how to add a progress bar? how to update it? or which view to use (you could, for example, also use a stepper)?

Comment: I know how to add it, just how to update it based on the number of correct answers in a row. I have to use the progressbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class:

```
ProgressBar progressBar
```

In your onCreate:

```
 progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.answerProgress);
 progressBar.setMax(10);
 progressBar.setProgress(0);
```

and then in this part of your code

```
 if(answer == answerUser)
            {
                TextView Scores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
                score ++;
                progressBar.setProgress(score);
                ....
            }
```

In the XML, specify you want a horizontal progress bar, other wise it will be circular:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/answerProgress"
    />
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this should work, but I get a runtime exception "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(int)' on a null object reference". I have the bar on design, xml and called in class, I don't know where else should I look?

Comment: Did you specify it be horizontal in the XML? See my edit.

Comment: Ok I fixed it, instead of having the code in onCreate, I put it in the if(answer == answerUser). Thanks for your help :)